# XOR operation for two boolean field

Tags: c#, xor

Given two Boolean, how to come up with the most elegant **one liner** that computes the XOR operation in C#?

I know one can do this by a combination of `switch` or `if` `else` but that would make my code rather ugly.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
bool xorValue = bool1 ^ bool2;
```

Comment: I guess that there is no `^^` operator since short-circuiting XOR is not possible, since you have to evaluate both values in all cases.

Comment: I personally think that `bool ElegantResult = ElegantBoolean1 ^ ElegantBoolean2;` is a little more elegant... but I guess it's really in the eye of the beholder

Comment: It works because in C#, true = 1 and false = 0. If you're used to C/C++ and long Booleans, where there was 0 and non-0, a bit-wise OR triggers warning bells in your head. But that's not the case in C#. (Note that conversions to Boolean are still 0 and non-0, but that's not how they're stored.)  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Boolean);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 74):

Ok to add some context:
You can look here [Tables](https://web.archive.org/web/20180223015935/https://www.learn-c.com/boolean.htm)

There you can see that "exclusive or" is basically the same as "not equal". So you could just use this (with boolean):

```
if (X != Y)...
```

But if you want to directly show people you mean "XOR" just use the other answers here.

Comment: I loved this solution. Should be up.

Comment: I'd say this is a lot more readable than the XOR operator option, since many developers could not know the XOR operator and misinterpret the code

Answer (score 17):

C# has [logical XOR operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/xor-operator) `^`. Here's how you do it.

```
bool result = x ^ y // x XOR y
```

Comment: To be explicit, ^ is a bit-wise OR, it just happens to work as a logical OR because the bits of Boolean values are all 0's (=false) or all 0's and a lone 1 bit (=true).

Answer (score 0):

I think it should help:

```
A ^ B ? TrueOperation() : FalseOperation();
```